# Speaker transplant between iPhone 6 Plus and 6s Plus

Tags: iphone, ios, hardware, repair, speakers

I have an iPhone 6s Plus and looking forward to giving it to my little sister. She complains the speaker is too quiet and that's true. You can barely hear any audio from both the earpiece and the loudspeaker. I also happened to have an old iPhone 6 Plus which I drenched in water and not working anymore. Apple said it was irreparable since then it sat on my cupboard for years. I wonder if I could transplant the earpiece and loudspeaker from the water damaged 6 Plus to the 6s Plus. I have concerns regarding this because I know both the iPhones (6 Plus and 6s Plus) look identical from the outside (Except the thickness) but the 6s generation was the first set of iPhones to introduce 3D touch which works with the help of the Taptic Engine.
[image]

The Taptic Engine takes a significant amount of space inside the phone and hence I am worried if they had to change the internal design of the speaker in order to recive haptic feedbacks. I don't really have anything to lose. Both the phones are not in use currently so I don't mind if they become totally unuseable anymore. What I mean to say is even if the process of speaker transplant is difficult. I still wouldn't mind cause I am just doing this for fun. I'd save some penny and get some experience of fixing stuff

**The question**

- Does the iPhone 6s Plus and 6 Plus have the same Earpiece and
  Loudspeaker design?
- Is it difficult to transplant the speakers? I saw an IFixIt guide and
  it doesn't seem that bad
- I also have a dead 5S. Any chances of that speaker to fit in the 6s Plus?

Thanks a lot for spending time in reading this question.